# NHibernate criar banco de dados?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Sou desenvolvedor Java e trabalho com Hibernate. Agora preciso criar uma aplicação desktop e decidi usar o C# para isto. Andei pesquisando frameworks ORM para C# e encontrei o Entity Framework e o NHibernate. Como minha experiência eh maior com o Hibernate resolvi adotar o NHibernate mas estou pesquisando se eh possivel o framework criar o banco de dados e as tabelas assim como é possivel no Hibernate mas ainda não encontrei nada além de criação de tabelas.

Gostaria de saber se com o NHibernate é possível criar o banco de dados ?

Comment: Usando o Fluent é possível, sem usá-lo eu nunca vi.

Comment: @jbueno perfeito, obrigado. Para trabalhar com MySQL vc sabe me dizer quais as bibliotecas necessárias ?

Comment: @FernandoPaiva, as opções para configurar o NHibernate para criar ou não as tabelas no banco de dados são as 3 Schema listados e explicados [nessa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/129152/2998).

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde @FernandoPaiva eu faço desta maneira com Nhibernate ele cria as tabelas no banco vou deixar link do github com projeto que usei ele.

```
 public class HibernateUtil
    {
        private static ISessionFactory factory;

        public static ISessionFactory Factory
        {
            get
            {
                if (factory == null)
                {

                    factory = Fluently.Configure()
                        .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                        .ConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["webapi"].ConnectionString))
                        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<FuncionarioMap>()).
                         ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false, true))
                        .BuildSessionFactory();


                }


                return factory;
            }


        }
    }
```

https://github.com/EduardoSampaio/ControleFuncionario/blob/master/Projeto.Dal/Util/HibernateUtil.cs

Comment: Eu tbm faço assim, mas dessa maneira o banco de dados não é criado apenas as tabelas. Eu estou procurando uma maneira de criar o banco de dados e também as tabelas.

Comment: Bom com Nhibernate não conheço essa opção sei que Entity Framework a casos que ele até cria banco automaticamente.

Comment: O Entity Framework cria o banco automaticamente junto com as tabelas ?

Comment: Ele consegue criar até arquivo mdf dentro do visual studio , ou você pode usar terminal package manager console  pode sugir o banco com comandos Enable-Migrations  e depois usando  update-database -verbose