# Lentidão com FluentNHibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, assincronismo

Estou utilizando FluentNHibernate em uma aplicação simples de cadastro de produtos.

A primeira vez que eu executo algo que acesse a base de dados(tela de consulta de produtos ou cadastro um produto) o site fica carregando por um tempo longo. Porem após esse primeiro carregamento o sistema faz as mesmas coisas rapidamente.

Exemplo:
Entro pela primeira vez na tela de consulta de produtos o sistema fica carregando por um longo tempo. Depois que carrega se eu volto e acesso novamente a tela de consulta de produtos o sistema carrega rápido.

Sabem me informar o que o sistema carrega neste primeiro acesso e se é possível tornar isto assíncrono logo no carregamento da Home do site?

Obrigado.

Comment: Qual o banco de dados está utilizando? Essa lentidão é em qualquer "primeira" consulta? Poderia postar sua `query` na pergunta?

Comment: Estou usando SQL Server. Não necessariamente consulta. Se a primeira coisa, com acesso a base, que eu faço no site é a inclusão do produto então a inclusão que vai demorar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não necessariamente isso será uma resposta, mas talvez o ajude!

**Configurações**

Alguns questionamentos sobre suas configurações:

1. Como você está configurando a sessão do NHibernate?
2. Está utilizando qual Schema? `SchemaUpdate`? `SchemaExport`?
3. O NHibernate está criando as suas tabelas?

Basicamente essas configurações dissem se o NHibernate vai comparar os metadatas de suas tabelas com o seu Mapeamento, e se vai criar alguma [DDL(Data Definition Language)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) na base de dados (Isso impacta diretamente na primeira conexão).

Posso demonstrar 3 cenários de configuração para comparar com suas configurações:

- `new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(false, true); // apagar o database e criar novamente todas as tabelas` (recomendado apenas para utilizar em testes, pois os dados/tabelas serão apagados a cada nova conexão, **NUNCA em produção**);
- `new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false, true); // atualizar o database, acrescentando novas tabelas e colunas sem excluir o que não está no mapeamento` (recomendado para utilizar em testes, e na fase de desenvolvimento enquanto se está modelando as tabelas, **NUNCA em produção**, pois irá comparar os metadata da base de dados com o mapeamento e acrescentar as DDL que não estiverem na base de dados);
- `new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(false, false); // normal, não criar nenhum DDL no database` (Recomendado, para qualquer fase do desenvolvimento, se você não deseja que o NHibernate altere sua estrutura da base de dados, e essa configuração não faz comparação de metadatas e nem cria nenhuma DDL ao criar a conexão, DEVE ser utilizado em produção, pois é a configuração que menos tem *overflow* na inicialização).

**Sobre inicializar o NHibernate ao inicializar o sistema!**

Você pode inicializar a conexão do Nhibernate a qualquer momento executando qualquer rotina na base de dados (consulta, insert, etc).

Você pode simplesmente no Controller do Home fazer uma consulta simples para inicializar o NHibernate. Ou pode fazer isso na inicialização do sistema, como por exemplo no `Application_Start()` no `Globa.asax.cs` no caso do ASP.NET < 5, ou no `Startup.cs` no ASP.NET 5.